# Limit the number of mod_mono_server4 process instances to match the number of Apache server processes started up at Ubuntu 16.04 reboot timee?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, apache-httpd, process-management, mono

How do I limit the number of mod_mono_service process instances to match the number of Apache server processes started up at Ubuntu 16.04 reboot time?

The way to specify the number of Apache server processes started up at Ubuntu 16.04 reboot time is to place the StartServers directive in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

Using the answer I saw in this Stack Overflow article, [[Limiting number of processes by name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123153/limiting-number-of-processes-by-name]), I already tried setting MaxConnections in my systemd directory's apache.service file shown directly below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache service

[Service]
Type=simple
MaxConnections=3
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2

[Install]
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.apache2.service
```

The reason I want to do this is to avoid using the extra CPU and RAM memory resources consumed by extra mod_mono_service process instance(s).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the `C` source code for `mod_mono.c` in GitHub, I found
that it is the Linux system programmer's responsibility to specify the creation of the correct number of `mod_mono_server4` process instances.

In addition, it is the responsibility of the Linux system programmer to make sure that the matching of each specific `mod_mono_server` instance with an unique `apache2` process is correct.

Comment: @heemayl, Would you please tell me if my answer to this question is correct?

Comment: Hello Frank, I have no idea. I have just done the editing. I have not given any vote too as i am not sure.